# Google Maps doesn't render properly in Meteor Cordova

Tags: cordova, meteor, google-maps-api-3

Hi guys i have a problem with dburles Google Maps and Meteor Cordova App. i have this html

```
<template name="googleMapsStatusFree">
    <div class="map-container">
        {{> googleMap name="map" options=mapOptions}}
    </div>
</template>
```

and this js onCreated

```
    Template.googleMapsStatusFree.onCreated(function () {

    // We can use the `ready` callback to interact with the map API once the map is ready.
    GoogleMaps.ready('map', function (map) {

        //definisco le variabili che mi serviranno
        let marker;

        //Array che contiente i marker e che ad ogni cambio di prodotto viene svuotato
        let gmarkers = [];

        //Funzione firata ad ogni cambio di prodotto
        Tracker.autorun(function () {

            if (variabileReattivaRispostaApp.get() || variabileReattivaHistoryProduct.get()) {

                //svuoto i marker precedentemente settati
                for(let i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++){
                    gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
                }

                if (variabileReattivaRispostaApp.get()){

                    console.log("Scansionato");

                    let lat = variabileReattivaRispostaApp.get().ProdottoLat;
                    let lng = variabileReattivaRispostaApp.get().ProdottoLng;

                    //e restituisco il marker
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                        map: map.instance,
                    });

                    //lo aggiungo alla lista
                    gmarkers.push(marker);

                    //e setto le proprieta della nuova mappa
                    map.instance.setCenter({
                        lat: lat,
                        lng: lng
                    });
                    map.instance.setZoom(10)
                }

                if (variabileReattivaHistoryProduct.get()){

                    console.log("History")


                    let lat = variabileReattivaHistoryProduct.get().ProdottoLat;
                    let lng = variabileReattivaHistoryProduct.get().ProdottoLng;

                    //e restituisco il marker
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                        map: map.instance,
                    });

                    //lo aggiungo alla lista
                    gmarkers.push(marker);

                    //e setto le proprieta della nuova mappa
                    map.instance.setCenter({
                        lat: lat,
                        lng: lng
                    });
                    map.instance.setZoom(10)
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and this helper

```
Template.googleMapsStatusFree.helpers({

    //Funziona che viene passata al template per la mappa
    mapOptions: function () {

        // Make sure the maps API has loaded
        if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {

            let lat;
            let lng;

            if (variabileReattivaHistoryProduct.get()) {
                lat = variabileReattivaHistoryProduct.get().ProdottoLat;
                lng = variabileReattivaHistoryProduct.get().ProdottoLng
            }

            if (variabileReattivaRispostaApp.get()) {
                lat = variabileReattivaRispostaApp.get().ProdottoLat;
                lng = variabileReattivaRispostaApp.get().ProdottoLng
            }

            console.log(lat + "," + lng);


            //ritorno le opzioni tra cui le coordinate memorizzate nel prodotto selezionato
            return {
                name: 'map',
                element: document.getElementById('map'),
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                zoom: 10
            };

        }
    },
});
```

and StartUp

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
   GoogleMaps.load()
})
```

now i have this result:

when i click for the first time i have this issue: google map render, but doesn't show the layer of map like this image

[image: fail]

when a click on resize map on top right i have this

[image: fullscreen]

and then when i resize. I have the desired result.

[image: result]

So, how can I have the desired result on the first try?

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue sometimes, and this snippet is a working workaround for me:

`google.maps.event.trigger(map.instance, 'resize');`

Place that at the end of your `GoogleMaps.ready()` function.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I try in week and let you know, thank you very much! :)

Comment: Did you get this working? 
I had resize events and got stumped. Thought I needed the 'googlemaps' Cordova plugin